# Solve $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)f(x-t)dt=e^{2x}-1,$ where $f(x)$ is continuous and nonnegative, for $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve an integral equation as follow:
$$
\int_{0}^{x}f(t)f(x-t)dt=e^{2x}-1, \textrm{where }f(x) \textrm{ is continuous and nonnegative.}
$$
I want to solve such $f(x)$，but after trying to take the derivative of both sides of the equation, I still have no idea. The only thing I get is $f(0)=\sqrt{2}$. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Actually if we only assume $f$ is continuous, then we can't even take the derivative. So I think if we need to assume $f$ is smooth or something like this?

Comment: This equation has a convolutional form $f*f(x)=e^{2x}-1$ under the following restriction: $x>0$. Usually, this kind of equation is solved using Laplace transform, but here I don't see how it could give an explicit solution...

Answer (score 6):

With Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)f(x-t)dt=\mathcal{L}(e^{2x}-1)$$
$$(\mathcal{L}f)^2=\dfrac{1}{s-2}-\dfrac1s$$
$$\mathcal{L}(f)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s(s-2)}}$$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{2}e^tI_0(x)$$
where $I_0(t)=J_0(it)$ is Bessel function.

Comment: [+1] I had not been able to identify the last Laplace transform !

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I need to know more about the Laplace transform.